# how can I write a aspx web service in c# like this php web service

Tags: c#, android, web-services

I have written this php web service that receive data form an android app,
but now I want to send the data from the android app to the web service written in C# aspx.
Who can convert this php code to aspx and thanks so much for any help

```
<?php

$data = array("result" => 0, "message" => "Error!");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

        $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
        $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];

        // check account 

} else
$data = array("hasAccount" => false, "userType" => "","account_status"=>0);

/* Output header */


header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Stack is not a code-converter service. However it´s for specific programing-related questions with the main-purpose on *learning*. What would you learn if someone writes the code for you?

Comment: Not the kind of question to ask here. None should do the work for you. Instead try to do your work and ask for help.

Comment: I think it is a simple code I do not know how to receive data in aspx

Comment: what do you mean by this? you want a c# code for a web service?

Answer (score 0):

Step by step of creating a web service in C#:

1.)Create new Project

[image]

2.)
[image]

3.)

[image]

4.)

[image]

5.)

[image]

Good Luck..